# Error PHP 7.0 and SSL TLS 1.0

Tags: php, ssl, soap, ssl-certificate, php-7

Im having a problem with SoapClient and PHP 7.0 to parse wsdl.

Im getting this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ws.ocasa.com/testecommerce/service.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://ws.ocasa.com/testecommerce/service.asmx?wsdl"
```

If you put this URL in a browser you can see the SOAP, and also in SoapUI it works OK.

I'm using laravel 5.4, and my code is:

```
$client = new \SoapClient('https://ws.ocasa.com/testecommerce/service.asmx?wsdl',
    ['soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2]);
```

I noticed that that website is under SSL TLS 1.0. If I change PHP to 5.6, it works perfect, but with PHP 7.0 it does not work.

If I change to this other WSDL:

```
https://id3check.gb.co.uk/gbportalinternational/aspx/id3check_1b.asmx?WSDL
```

Everything works fine.

Thank you

Comment: probably the non-functional url is a server not giving a valid ssl certificate for that domain

Comment: I think that is caused by the old TLS version and the absolute cipher that is used. Perhaps you can write them to make a better configuration for the webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could choose to ignore a bad cert:

```
$endpoint = new SOAPClient($url,
    array(
      'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,
      'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
        array(
          'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false, 
            'verify_peer_name' => false
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

This would be a solution, should you not have access to the soap server to correct the certificate, or be able to elsewise make your server accept the certificate.

This should be the last solution as indeed you ignore all warnings something is wrong

Comment: But the certificate is correct. And when you do that you disable the verification.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373328/how-do-i-get-the-php-soap-client-to-communicate-with-a-service-running-over-ssl

Comment: This way, the problem comes when I call a function. Here is the code:

 $response = $this->client->__call("GenerarRetiros",array($params),[
            'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
                array(
                    'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false
                    )
                )
            )
        ]);