# PHP Soap call over SSL

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to make a SOAP call in PHP over SSL but I get an error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://mydomain.com/report' : failed to load external entity
>   "https://mydomain.com/report"

I read stuff onlinle and tried to solve it with the following:
1. Copy ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll to your windows system32 directory and Uncommenting extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001003/php-soap-cannot-connect-to-an-ssl-wsdl-source))
2. Adding the following code the the SoapClient instance (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443618/disable-certificate-verification-in-php-soapclient)):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
));

$client  = new SoapClient(null, array( 
    'location' => 'https://...',
    'uri' => '...', 
    'stream_context' => $context
));
```

Both of these didn't help and I still get the error.
Have any idea what to do?

Comment: You've verified that SSL is properly configured on your server, e.g. by hitting that ssl url in a browser manually?

Comment: I'm trying to make the call from my local which doesn't have a certificate.

Comment: then you're probably running into trouble for that. you'll have to explicitly disable cert/CA checking and whatnot to accept a 'bad' ssl server.

Comment: How do I explicitly disable cert/CA?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

Comment: The link is describes exactly what I've done in #2.